# Join/Pivot items with EAV table

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot, entity-attribute-value

I have a table like below which would have the product description

```
╔════╦══════════════╦══════╗
║ Id ║  name        ║ price║
╠════╬══════════════╬══════╣
║  1 ║ Apple        ║ 23   ║
║  2 ║ shirt        ║  148 ║
║  3 ║ computer     ║  101 ║
║  4 ║ printer      ║  959 ║
╚════╩══════════════╩══════╝
```

and another table which is holding the attributes like linked by the ID

```
╔════╦══════════════╦══════╗
║ Id ║  attr_name   ║ Value║
╠════╬══════════════╬══════╣
║  1 ║ color        ║ red  ║
║  1 ║ size         ║  xl  ║
║  1 ║ brand        ║  App ║
║  2 ║ color        ║  blue║
║  2 ║ size         ║  l   ║
║  3 ║ color        ║  blue║
║  3 ║ size         ║  xxl ║
║  3 ║ brand        ║  HP  ║
╚════╩══════════════╩══════╝
```

Is there any possible way to bring a table like below if I know the attribute name is going to be only color size and brand

```
╔════╦══════════╦═══════╦═══════╦══════╦══╗
║ id ║   name   ║ color ║ brand ║ size ║  ║
╠════╬══════════╬═══════╬═══════╬══════╬══╣
║  1 ║ apple    ║ red   ║ app   ║ xl   ║  ║
║  2 ║ shirt    ║ blue  ║       ║ l    ║  ║
║  3 ║ computer ║ blue  ║ HP    ║ XXL  ║  ║
║  4 ║ printer  ║       ║       ║      ║  ║
╚════╩══════════╩═══════╩═══════╩══════╩══╝
```

Comment: Do you really want to merge the tables or do you want a query to get those values on display?

Comment: @PatrickHofman I would like to query to get those values, so that I can create a new table from it.

Comment: The term for this structure is ["EAV"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model).

Comment: @user3199077 What version of Oracle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use an aggregate function with a CASE expression to convert the rows into columns:

```
select d.id,
  d.name,
  max(case when a.attr_name = 'color' then a.value end) color,
  max(case when a.attr_name = 'brand' then a.value end) brand,
  max(case when a.attr_name = 'size' then a.value end) size
from product_description d
inner join product_attributes a
  on d.id = a.id
group by d.id, d.name;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5653e/7).

Since you are using Oracle 11g, then you can use the PIVOT function to get the result:

```
select id, name, Color, Brand, "Size"
from
(
  select d.id, d.name,
    a.attr_name, a.value
  from product_description d
  inner join product_attributes a
    on d.id = a.id
) src
pivot
(
  max(value)
  for attr_name in ('color' as Color,
                    'brand' as Brand,
                    'size' as "Size")
) p;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5653e/17)