# I want to convert multiple rows into mutiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table looks like below, it has one column 'Username';

```
UserName
------------
Vinod
Konangi
vk@gmail.com
Draft
```

I want the output as

```
Name   Surname    email            status 
------------------------------------------
Vinod   konangi   vk@gmail.com     one
```

Can someone please help me out

Comment: What are the other columns in the table that has this column Username?

Comment: How will you know third row is email , second row is surname, what should happen when there is another user details.Is this is the only column in yourtable

Comment: A table of this nature is common in many web based applications (possibly using an Entity–attribute–value model (EAV)) this means "meta data" exists on each row of that table to indicate "Name" "Surname" etc. To provide you with a more complete answer `we do need to know about the other columns of that table`. Here is an example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21836757/join-pivot-items-with-eav-table that question does provide the needed information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `PIVOT` to rotate the data from one column into multiple columns.

[Simple example](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/05/22/sql-server-pivot-table-example/)

Answer (score 1):

This will return multiple row into one column.

```
SELECT UserName + ' ' 
FROM [WriteTableNameHere]
FOR XML PATH('')
```

Comment: Looks like he want the result in multiple columns not in a single column